# Accidently pulled code from repository and now the code I was working on is gone. Can I revert it back?

Tags: git, gitlab, revert

I was writing code and then I tried to commit the code but I got a message saying I have not pulled beforehand. Instinctively I pulled but later I saw that all the code I wrote was gone and was changed with the current one in Gitlab. Is there possibility to revert back to the code I had saved on my local machine ?

I do not know if it will be of any help but I can see the commit I tried to send when using `git reflog`.

I get `222a4f0 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: commit: mymessage`.

Comment: Can you check `git stash list` and see if your code is there ?

Comment: When I type `git stash list` nothing happens. But when I use `git reflog`  I see `222a4f0 (HEAD -> main) HEAD@{0}: commit: mymessage` which is my last commit that did not happen and the one I want to revert to.

Comment: `HEAD` and `HEAD@{0}` are the current commit. So if that output from reflog is supposed to include your current changes, then they will be in your current working tree. It sounds like there is more going on here, so you need to inspect the entire history with `git log --oneline --graph` to see where your changes are.

Comment: In the distant past—2007 or so—`git pull` had bugs that could destroy your own work just like this. They are long fixed, but I avoid `git pull` in part because of this. You might find that avoiding `git pull` is a good idea. It won't help you recover your code (which should still exist since these bugs are long fixed, so I don't know what happened here) but in general the advice "don't run git pull, use git fetch and a separate second command instead" will probably serve you well.